# Compare string and byte slice in Go without copy

Tags: go

What is the best way to check that Go string and a byte slice contain the same bytes? The simplest `str == string(byteSlice)` is inefficient as it copies `byteSlice` first.

I was looking for a version of [Equal(a, b []byte)](https://golang.org/src/bytes/bytes_decl.go?s=523:551#L7) that takes a string as its argument, but could not find anything suitable.

Comment: Not that in Go 1.5 there "is" a [strings.Compare](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/strings/compare.go), however it's by design extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Starting from Go 1.5 the compiler optimizes string(bytes) when comparing to a string using a [stack-allocated temporary](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/69cd91a5981c49eaaa59b33196bdb5586c18d289). Thus since Go 1.5

```
str == string(byteSlice)
```

became a canonical and efficient way to compare string to a byte slice.

Comment: Even in 1.7, I find that comparing the lengths first is faster in the case they are different:
`len(str) == len(byteSlice) && str == string(byteSlice)` - it looks like this is because Go does the creation of the temporary slice (with no alloc, but still takes a little time) before it compares length.

Answer (score 9):

If you're comfortable enough with the fact that this can break on a later release (doubtful though), you can use `unsafe`:

```
func unsafeCompare(a string, b []byte) int {
    abp := *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&a))
    return bytes.Compare(abp, b)
}

func unsafeEqual(a string, b []byte) bool {
    bbp := *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))
    return a == bbp
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/oXO4AH9L_q)

[Benchmarks](http://play.golang.org/p/WAR6RvJ203):

```
// using:
//  aaa = strings.Repeat("a", 100)
//  bbb = []byte(strings.Repeat("a", 99) + "b")

// go 1.5
BenchmarkCopy-8         20000000                75.4 ns/op
BenchmarkPetersEqual-8  20000000                83.1 ns/op
BenchmarkUnsafe-8       100000000               12.2 ns/op
BenchmarkUnsafeEqual-8  200000000               8.94 ns/op
// go 1.4
BenchmarkCopy           10000000                233  ns/op
BenchmarkPetersEqual    20000000                72.3 ns/op
BenchmarkUnsafe         100000000               15.5 ns/op
BenchmarkUnsafeEqual    100000000               10.7 ns/op
```

Comment: I don't think one should not propose to use package unsafe for premature optimizations. If the OP would have demonstrated that the conversion is the main bottleneck of his code, well maybe.

Comment: @Volker he explained that for his workload `str == string(byteSlice)` is inefficient because it copies it, which is understandable.

Comment: If it is not on his hot path it just does not matter if it is inefficient or very inefficient.

Comment: @Volker that highly depends on what he's trying to do, my method is a valid alternative.

Comment: The benchmark here assumes that the match is expected so the whole string should be scanned when nothing beats hand-coded assembler. Still this is a valid answer if one looks for fast universal solution and using unsafe code is OK.

Answer (score 8):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [String types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types)
>
> A string type represents the set of string values. A string value is a
>   (possibly empty) sequence of bytes. The predeclared string type is
>   string.
>
> The length of a string s (its size in bytes) can be discovered using
>   the built-in function len. A string's bytes can be accessed by integer
>   indices 0 through len(s)-1.

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func equal(s string, b []byte) bool {
    if len(s) != len(b) {
        return false
    }
    for i, x := range b {
        if x != s[i] {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func main() {
    s := "equal"
    b := []byte(s)
    fmt.Println(equal(s, b))
    s = "not" + s
    fmt.Println(equal(s, b))
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

Comment: In absence of a native implementation this is good enough universal replacement especially when on average match is not expected and the loop terminates after the first or second character

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use the unsafe package or something just to compare `[]byte` and `string`. The Go compiler is clever enough now, and it can optimize such conversions.

**[Here's a benchmark](https://play.golang.org/p/8kefbW8q2et):**

```golang
BenchmarkEqual-8                172135624                6.96 ns/op <--
BenchmarkUnsafe-8               179866616                6.65 ns/op <--
BenchmarkUnsafeEqual-8          175588575                6.85 ns/op <--
BenchmarkCopy-8                 23715144                 47.3 ns/op
BenchmarkPetersEqual-8          24709376                 47.3 ns/op
```

**Just convert a byte slice to a string and compare:**

```golang
var (
    aaa = strings.Repeat("a", 100)
    bbb = []byte(strings.Repeat("a", 99) + "b")
)

func BenchmarkEqual(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = aaa == string(bbb)
    }
}
```

---

[Here is more information about the optimization](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/gofrontend/+/170894), and [this](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/173323/).